# Javascript Find Emoji in String and Parse

Tags: javascript, string, emoji

After TONS of research, I have found how to parse emoji in realtime using the Twemoji library.

Now, I need to figure out how to identify if there's emoji within some text, grab the position of that emoji and execute the parsing function.

Some example text can be

```
It is a great day .
```

Need to find the  within the whole string and use the following function to get its hex code, return the surrogate pairs and parse with the Twemoji library.

```
function entityForSymbolInContainer(selector) {
    var code = data.message.body.codePointAt(0);
    var codeHex = code.toString(16);
    while (codeHex.length < 4) {
        codeHex = "0" + codeHex;
    }

    return codeHex;
}

// Get emoji hex code
    var emoji = entityForSymbolInContainer(data.message.body);
// For given an HEX codepoint, returns UTF16 surrogate pairs
    var emoji = twemoji.convert.fromCodePoint(emoji);
// Given a generic string, it will replace all emoji with an <img> tag
    var emoji = twemoji.parse(emoji);
```

I am using the following check to see if there's emoji within the text. Problem is that for a simple grinning face () it doesn't alert me. However, if I type in the "shirt and tie" () it will alert me to that.

```
var string = "It is a great day .";
var emojiRegex = /([\uE000-\uF8FF]|\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDDFF])/g;

if (string.match(emojiRegex)) {
    alert("emoji found");
}
```

Please help on the issue of the regex not picking up the emoji. After that, I should be able to just find that within the string.

Thank you!

Comment:  is U+1F600, which is encoded in UTF-16 as \uD83D\uDE00. Your regular expression does not consider that to be an emoji. (It stops at \uD83D\uDDFF.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Do you know of a resource for a more complete regex?

Comment: Before you can develop an algorithm to detect emoji, you first need to have a clear definition as to what an emoji is. Whoever wrote that regex didn't consider U+1F600 to be an emoji.

Answer (score 10):

Nowadays with ES2018 we can use Unicode Property Escapes in a regex match:

```
\p{…}
```

For simple emojis it would be:

```
"Be kind , smile".match(/\p{Emoji}+/gu)
```

For emojis including glyphs glued with ZERO WIDTH JOINER like ‍‍‍ it can be:

```
"My Family ‍‍‍".match(/[\p{Emoji}\u200d]+/gu)
```

Comment: Short, efficient ! Thank you!

Comment: The second regex breaks when multiple emojis are together. The following works: `\p{Emoji}(\u200d\p{Emoji})*`, because it only matches an emoji list _concatenated_ with zero-width joiners, rather than just having them mixed in anywhere.

Answer (score 9):

In 2021 the best way to do this is using the support for unicode in regular expressions that brought ES6.

It's as simple as using this regular expression:

`/(\p{Emoji_Presentation}|\p{Extended_Pictographic})/gu`

For example, this simple function will replace with blanks all of the emojis in a string:

```js
function removeEmojis(str) {
    var emojiRE = /(\p{Emoji_Presentation}|\p{Extended_Pictographic})/gu;
    return str.replace(emojiRE, '');
}

removeEmojis('This ❌ hs some  emojis inside'); //'This  hs some  emojis inside'
```

It uses both the `Emoji_Representation`and the `Extended_Pictographic` properties so it doesn't count numbers, `#` and `*` in the search, [as indicated by the Unicode standard](https://unicode.org/reports/tr51/#Emoji_Properties).

We can use the abbreviations for these properties too, for a shorter regular expression:

`/(\p{EPres}|\p{ExtPict})/gu`

You can test drive it here:

```js
function removeEmojis(str) {
    var emojiRE = /\p{EPres}|\p{ExtPict}/gu;
    return str.replace(emojiRE, '');
}

var testStr = 'This ❌ hs some  emojis inside';
console.log('Test string: ' + testStr);
console.log('Result: ' + removeEmojis(testStr));
```

Comment: This is good, but doesn't include emojis that use zero-width joiners. I ended up using: `/(\p{EPres}|\p{ExtPict})(\u200d(\p{EPres}|\p{ExtPict}))*/gu`

Answer (score 6):

This post gives a very comprehensive regex for matching emojis with a very good explanation. He bases his regex on the one published by lodash library.

```
(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])
```

https://medium.com/@thekevinscott/emojis-in-javascript-f693d0eb79fb

Answer (score 3):

**This determines if there is an emoji in the comment.**

```
var unified_emoji_ranges = ['\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]','\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f]','\ud83d[\ude80-\udeff]'];

var reg = new RegExp(unified_emoji_ranges.join('|'), 'g');

var string = "It is a great day .";

if (string.match(reg)) {
    alert("emoji found");
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation :)

Comment: didn't work for me with ✅

Answer (score 0):

The problem:

> JavaScript defines strings as sequences of UTF-16 code
>   units, not as sequences of characters or code points.

(quoted from source below)

You have to set up the RegExp with surrogate pairs:

I have found a good solution/exlanation here [parsing emoji unicode in javascript](http://crocodillon.com/blog/parsing-emoji-unicode-in-javascript) that does without an extra library. 
And here's an online [Surrogate Pair Calculator](http://russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm).

And in your case:

```
/\uD83D\uDE00/
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wnmaCB/2)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for a solution in JS to find emoji's in string.

Can use the following [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex) (emoji-regex).

Here is an example converting all the emojis to Unicode hexadecimal numerical representation of character in a given string:

```
import emojiRegex  from 'emoji-regex/RGI_Emoji.js';
const emojiRegexPattern = emojiRegex();
const stringThatMightHaveEmojis = ...; //some string that can contain emoji's..

stringThatMightHaveEmojis.replace(emojiRegexPattern,(m, idx) => {
      return `${m.codePointAt(0).toString(16)}]`;
    })
```

There are more examples in the documentation of the library.

Plus a helpful article I stumbled upon explaining parsing emoji's, codePointAt can be found [here](https://thekevinscott.com/emojis-in-javascript/)