# How to parse Emoji-Mart emojis without react.js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, emoji

I'm trying to run emoji-mart as follows:

1. Include `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emoji-mart@latest/dist/browser.js"></script>`
2. Render the picker:

```
emojiOptions = { ... };
const picker = new EmojiMart.Picker(emojiOptions);

emojiMenu.html(picker);
```

Everything works fine at this point. But I can't find a way to parse the native emojis in the DOM. Is there a way to replace native emojis with their corresponding (images?) in the document body without React component?

I tried to find the necessary libraries to run some parser but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Confused by your use of (images?).

If they're not appearing as images try `document.body.appendChild(picker)` from [Browser Example](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart#browser)  With jquery `append()` would probably also work.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-questions/34363972) `.html` and `.append` are not the same type of behavior.

If the issue is getting a reference to the emoji:

Further down in the examples at [Get emoji data from native](https://github.com/missive/emoji-mart#-get-emoji-data-from-native) you can also pull out the emoji ID and then do whatever you want with the data.

```
import data from '@emoji-mart/data'
import { init, getEmojiDataFromNative } from 'emoji-mart'

init({ data })

getEmojiDataFromNative('').then(console.log)
/* {
  aliases: ['hand_with_index_and_middle_fingers_crossed'],
  id: 'crossed_fingers',
  keywords: ['hand', 'with', 'index', 'and', 'middle', 'good', 'lucky'],
  name: 'Crossed Fingers',
  native: '',
  shortcodes: ':crossed_fingers::skin-tone-6:',
  skin: 6,
  unified: '1f91e-1f3ff',
} */
```

If the issue is identifying them in the text after they've already been placed and parsing them later, then you can try the work from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089427/javascript-find-emoji-in-string-and-parse).  Litzer's answer especially offers a fairly easy alternative.